# How to calculate totals of group_by variables in R in one go?

Tags: r

What are my options in calculating wages and totals of the group_by variables in to the same output? My current code is:

```
DF %>%
  group_by(job,gender) %>%
  summarize(wage = mean(wage, na.rm=T),
            people = sum (people))
```

Output is:

```
 
Job      gender  wage   people
Analyst    M     4500     321
Analyst    F     4800     121
Nurse      M     3000     34
Nurse      F     3400     643
```

I would like to get

```
 
Job      gender  wage   people
Analyst    M     4500     321
Analyst    F     4800     121
Analyst  Total   4570     442 
Nurse      M     3000     34
Nurse      F     3400     643
Nurse    Total   3365     677
Total      M     4000     355
Total      F     3800     794
Total    Total   3870     1149
```

My only idea is to calculate the totals to another DF and then bind all the DF to one. Is there a more elegant way in doing it. I mean already in the first code to say that hey please calculate total values of the group_by variables also.

NB! It's not important to me that the totals be called "Total" if R marks it another way its fine for me.

NB! All the numbers are fictional subtotal wages are not correct but in the right ballpark.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I think the approach to calculate totals and adding it to original `DF` would be the most easiest one.

Comment: Thank you. :) I will just calculate the different DF and rbind them to one.

Comment: question: how do you get 4570 as the total wage for analyst? If I use the weighted mean, I get 4582?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I'm a bit late to the party but here's one solution to your question using janitor::adorn_totals(), just need to replace mtcars data frame to your data frame:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl, am) %>% 
  summarise(mpg = sum(mpg)) %>%
  group_map(~ .x %>%
          janitor::adorn_totals("row"),.keep = T) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```